# "illustrated IN figure" vs. "illustrated BY figure"

Tags: phrase-usage

When we write an article about a specific topic, we want to exemplify what we try to explain. In this case, we add a picture in that article.

When mentioning this picture, which one is true?

> 1. *Explanation*, as illustrated **in** figure 1.
> 2. *Explanation*, as illustrated **by** figure 1.

The first sentence seems to me more appropriate, but I am not sure.

Comment: [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=65811353) reports 371 results for `illustrated in figure` and 9 for `illustrated by figure`, and [BNC](https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=65811391) agrees with 210 and 5 results respectively. So, while the *by* usage is attested, I would use *in*.

Comment: It depends on whether the explanation is illustrated by the entire graphic (use *by*) or by something in the graphic (use *in*).